# Avoid automatically going to single usage on ctrl+click in Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea

In IntelliJ by default `ctrl+click` does `Show Usages` and depending on the number of usages found either goes to the usage (one result) or opens a list (two or more results).

Is there any way to always show the list even on single results?

[image]

Comment: Can you offer some information regarding keymap profile and OS?

Comment: It seems that there is no special setting for this, but you can try Ctrl + Alt + Shift + F7 and press Enter. To minimize the amount of work, try recording a macro according to https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/using-macros-in-the-editor.html#record-a-macro , and assign a shortcut to it in Keymap settings.

Comment: @afterburner I'm on Linux, using a netbeans derived keymap

Comment: @EgorKlepikov Opening the tool window with that or right click > find usages seems the only ways so far